# Stripe plan update URI::InvalidURIError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-6

I create an update method based on the creation, the only difference is in changing the stripe method, but unfortunately I get an error, although the logic is identical

```
update_feature_plans_job.rb
class UpdateFeaturePlansJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(service)
    key = service.user.access_code
    Stripe.api_key = key

    service.features.each do |feature|
      Stripe::Plan.update({
                            id: "#{feature.title.parameterize}-feature_#{feature.id}",
                            amount: (feature.amount.to_r * 100).to_i,
                            currency: 'eur',
                            interval: 'month',
                            product: { name: feature.title },
                            nickname: feature.title.parameterize
                          })
    end
  end
end
```

service_controller:

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @service.update(service_params)
        UpdateFeaturePlansJob.perform_now(@service)
        format.html { redirect_to @service, notice: 'service was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @service }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @service.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

To be honest, the update is built identically to the creation. The only difference is the method in Stripe
The creation works perfectly

```
class CreateFeaturePlansJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(service)
    key = service.user.access_code
    Stripe.api_key = key

    service.features.each do |feature|
      Stripe::Plan.create({
        id: "#{feature.title.parameterize}-feature_#{feature.id}",
        amount: (feature.amount.to_r * 100).to_i,
        currency: 'eur',
        interval: 'month',
        product: { name: feature.title },
        nickname: feature.title.parameterize
      })
    end
  end
end
```

I want to fix the update method so that the data reaches Stripe correctly

But error:

URI::InvalidURIError in ServicesController#update

bad URI(is not URI?): "/v1/plans/{:id=>\"feature-title-feature_14\", :amount=>1000, :currency=>\"eur\", :interval=>\"month\", :product=>{:name=>\"Feature Title\"}, :nickname=>\"feature-title\"}"

```
Extracted source (around line #9):

9  Stripe::Plan.update({
```

```
Request
Parameters:

{"_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"aErX41FPUztfEjbILjgHGojdaCJsDp3jwlwAhnIoab2_JEZjRffBIEv0ZvH7RpNwSAZzUOmMBYzxX__qvTElgQ",
 "service"=>
  {"title"=>"Test Title",
   "goal"=>"100",
   "color"=>"#FFFFFF",
   "location"=>"Berlin",
   "description"=>"<div>Description main</div>",
   "features_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "title"=>"Feature Title", "description"=>"desc feature", "amount"=>"10.0", "quantity"=>"1", "id"=>"14"}}},
 "commit"=>"Update Service",
 "id"=>"5"}
```

I am a novice developer, please suggest a solution instead of criticism;(

Answer (score 2):

> To be honest, the update is built identically to the creation.

That's the problem - you're setting arguments in the update method that are only intended for the create method.

Supported parameters for the create method:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans/create?lang=ruby

Supported parameters for the update method:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans/update?lang=ruby

This is a voluntary limitation for Plan and Price updates - there is nearly no argument supported in the update method - mainly for compliance reasons.

Related documentation:
https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/manage-prices#edit-price

EDIT - actually, the problem is that you set the 'id' as an argument instead of in quotes before your arguments as outlined by @smathy and documented here:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans/update

Still, your call won't work if you fix this because of the above.

Answer (score 2):

Updated after comment from @Lucky2501 (thanks).

For operations on existing resources (ie. `retrieve`, `update`, `delete`) the first arg is the ID, so Stripe is reading your whole hash as the ID and hence using it to create the URL. You also are trying to change things you can't change, as per [the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans/update):

> By design, you cannot change a plan’s ID, amount, currency, or billing cycle.

Also changing the `product` needs to provide a product ID, AND (from the docs) "cannot be changed once it has been used in a subscription or subscription schedule"

So really that leaves you with this:

```rb
Stripe::Plan.update(
  "#{feature.title.parameterize}-feature_#{feature.id}",
    product: has_to_be_the_product_id,
    nickname: feature.title.parameterize
)
```

Comment: oh yeah - that's the reason for the error! Still, if it's corrected, they'll get another error since the method doesn't support these arguments.

Comment: Oh, ha, you're right.